# Não consigo editar HTML do wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

Estou editando um site feito sobre wordpress.org porém este site foi criado a alguns anos, eu consigo modificar o html da maneira que desejo, upo no servidor e o site passa a rodar com as minhas modificações, que são mínimas, troquei algumas imagens e um texto. Na hora fica tudo ok, porém no outro dia quando acesso o site ele está da mesma forma que estava antes de eu arrumar, já tentei tanta coisa e não sei mais o que fazer, estou a duas semanas nesse dilema, estou usando o sublime text para editar, e o filezilla para acessar o servidor via ftp e upar o arquivo .html modificado, meu servidor é locaweb. Por favor me deem um help! :(

No código dentro do cabeçado html da página que estou modificando tinha isso:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Feed" href="http://meudominio.com.br/feed/" />
```

cheguei a tirar mas não adiantou nada, no outro dia voltou tudo de novo ao jeito que estava antes.
baixei a pasta raiz do servidor (a pasta public_html) e editei a página que queria através do SublimeText, salvei e upei a pasta public_html novamente no servidor com as minhas alterações. A página que eu modifiquei estava no caminho: 
`C:\public_html\wp-content\cache\wp-rocket\meudomínio.com.br\‌​minhapasta\index.htm‌​l`

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que você está editando o arquivo num caminho que é descartável (cache). Os arquivos reais provavelmente estão em um caminho do tipo `wp-content/themes/my-theme`

Comment: neste caminho q vc passou só tem arquivos php e eu abri todos e não encontrei nada muito relevante ao meu problema e as pastas assets, languages, lib, templates, themeoptions e woocommerce. Sabe o q pode ser?

Comment: @Sarah acredito que seria interessante você dar uma olhada na hierarquia dos arquivos WordPress para entender onde esta cada conteúdo que deseja editar.

É bem provável que o que precisa esteja no header.php, poderá ler mais aqui:
https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

Comment: @Sarah só complementando a resposta: o markup do WP é escrito em grande parte através de templates, que são arquivos .php com html e algumas lógicas dentro. Na pasta de cache você encontrou arquivos html porque eles estão renderizados, prontos para serem interpretados pelo navegador, mas que só são guardados ali por motivos de performance. Toda vez que o cache é limpo (assumo que exista alguma cron no seu servidor que faça isso diariamente) esses arquivos são deletados e novos são gerados conforme os usuários acessam as páginas.

No mais, faço minhas as palavras do comentário acima.